# Is it possible to save this plant?

Tags: roots

(photos at the end)
Not sure what happened, but started getting weak and no longer standing, so it might be dying.
To me it seems the root is already bad/dead (soft and almost black).

Anything I can do to save it? Cut somewhere, separate, something?

I might have left the soil too wet, unfortunately. In the soil I could see some mold.

Sorry, I'm not sure what kind of plant, is this a succulent?

Thank you for any help!

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to tell what plant it might be - can you clarify by giving the following  information; 1. is this plant in a pot;  2. is it indoors or outside;  and can you add a photo of the plant itself rather than just parts of it, showing the pot it is in as well as the surface of the soil in the pot (if it is potted).

Comment: @Bamboo It was in a pot, indoors. This is the whole plant! I removed it because it got weak and I want to know how to treat it, just replant with new soil?

Comment: It may be far too late... but if you want to try, use a  clean pot with drainage holes that is not too big for the bits you have, and plant into new potting soil, water in well, let it drain down and then stand it somewhere to see if it grows. Do not water again until the surface of the soil feels dry, but not so dry its shrunk from the sides of the pot.